# Passing variable name in angular route

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute

Currently I am able to add routing mechanism in AngularJs with the following code :

```
App.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                templateUrl : '/templates/home.html',
                controller  : 'landing'
            })
        .when('/login', {
                templateUrl : '/templates/login.html',
                controller  : 'login'
            });
});
```

What I need is an url in the format like `/app/:appname` which should fetch template called `/template/:appname.html`. I know that the appname can be accessed from controller using :

```
$routeParams.appname;
```

But how can I render template based on that parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
App.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/app/:appname', {
                templateUrl : '/templates/app-template.html',
                controller  : 'AppCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    appPath: function ($route) {
                        return $route.current.params.appname;
                    }
                }
            })
});
```

in AppCtrl,

```
App.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

AppCtrl.$inject = [
    '$scope'
    'appPath'
];

function AppCtrl($scope, appPath) {
    $scope.template = appPath + '.html';
}
```

in app-template.html, use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) as such

```
<div ng-include src="template"></div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**templateUrl** can be use as function which returns a url.

```
App.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/templates/home.html',
            controller  : 'landing'
        })
        .when('/:appname',{
            templateUrl: function(params){
                return "templates/"+params.appname +".html"
            },
            controller: 'Ctrl'
        });
});
```

Comment: sorry but i can't accept more than one answer as correct. Both of the above are and working. :)